# Convert all XML elements without children to XML attributes of parent element

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Have the following xml input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EnvelopeType1>
    <Header>
        <User>user1</User>
        <Password>password</Password>
    </Header>
    <CustomerNumber>1</CustomerNumber>
    <CustomerName>Me</CustomerName>
    <Address>
        <Number>5</Number>
        <StreetName>High St</StreetName>
        <State>MI</State>
    </Address>
</EnvelopeType1>
```

And I need the following output after running it through an xslt:

```
<EnvelopeType1 CustomerNumber="1" CustomerName="Me"/>
    <Header User="user1" Password="password"/>
    <Address Number="5" StreetName="High St" State="MI"/>
</EnvelopeType1>
```

The root element may change to another type, and the contents inside the envelope may all change to different elements, etc, and also go several levels deep so I need something that can work generically.  There will never be existing attributes, its always going to be in elements, so there's no chance that a converted element will have the same name as an existing attribute.

I'm thinking this will use apply-templates and somehow go recursively through the nodes, but I'm not that cluey on XSLT, would appreciate any help with this.

There was another similar post here which I think would work, but requires XSLT2.0, I need something that would work with XSLT1.0

Comment: You forgot to include your XSLT code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a very generic solution to your problem. It makes only minimal assumptions about the nature of the input XML. What it *does* assume is only that elements that have child elements should include all of them as attributes.

Apart from that, any input XML will do. Tested with Saxon 6.5, try it online [here](http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rLX). What it does, in plain English, is:

> Match an element that has at least one child element. Copy this element to the
>   output. For each of its child element that does not itself have child
>   elements, add an attribute which is named after the "childless" child
>   element, and add its text content as the attribute value.

**Stylesheet**

**EDIT**: As a response to your comment. Now, the stylesheet gives the correct output for an arbitrary number of "levels".

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[*]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each select="*[not(*)]">
              <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EnvelopeType1 CustomerNumber="1" CustomerName="Me">
   <Header User="user1" Password="password"/>
   <Address Number="5" StreetName="High St" State="MI"/>
</EnvelopeType1>
```

Comment: Ooh, that online tool is quite cool and very useful.  Thanks for the code, I'm trying to go through it and try and understand what each line does.  It seemed to work ok when I first tried it, but when I went a step further and tried to add another child(with more elements below it) below the Header element, it ignored those

Comment: Something like this, to check that it can handle more embedded levels: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EnvelopeType1>
    <Header>
        <User>user1</User>
        <Password>password</Password>
        <HeaderChild>
            <Tag1>One</Tag1>
            <Tag2>Two</Tag2>
        </HeaderChild>
    </Header>
</EnvelopeType1>

Comment: @Kenbo Never post code in comments - it's unreadable there. I have edited the answer, and also updated it [here](http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rLX/2).

Comment: Again, danke for the code you've supplied.  Seems to work perfectly now. Will have to test it with a few more scenarios over the next few days but looks good to me.  I vaguely understand what each line is doing, but will need to spend more time with a xslt reference book I think.

Comment: @Kenbo Good to hear that you are willing to invest time understanding the concepts! In my answer, the "plain English" part is actually what the template does, line for line - if that helps you. Do not forget to _accept_ one of the two answers (mark the tick on the left so that it appears in green).

Comment: that actually makes perfect sense what you just said in "plain english" translated to the code.  I can see now how "*[*]" represents an element with child elements, "*[not(*)]" represents an element that does not have child elements, etc.. When you put it as simply as that, its almost like interpreting simple english :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you say you're not very clueful with respect to XSLT, I'm going to give you an answer that focuses on the conceptual issues, and not on the syntax.  (If you want a cut/paste solution, you'll have to look for other answers.)

You want a template which applies to any element.  So its match pattern can be `*`.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  ...
</
```

Inside that template, you want:

- to make an element with the same name as the context element
- to give that element attributes with the same name as all the childless and attribute-less children of the context element
- to give that element children corresponding to all the children of the context element which do have attributes or children

Since the second item in this list has to be handled before the first item, you will need two apply-templates instructions, one to produce attributes and one to produce children.  Use a distinct mode for the first one; optionally use a `select` attribute on each apply-templates call to make the call apply only to the appropriate children; alternatively, write do-nothing templates for the elements which should produce no output in a particular mode.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(@*) and not(*)]"
                         mode="attribute-generation"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[@* or *]"/>
  </
</
```

To make the stylesheet a bit more general, we'll preserve attributes in the input instead of assuming there aren't any.  (But for simplicity we will still assume there are never name collisions between attributes and children; checking for that would be a good exercise for an XSLT learner.)

```
<xsl:template match="@*"><xsl:copy/></xsl:template>
```

Finally, write a template to handle attribute-less, child-less elements in mode `attribute-generation`:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="attribute-generation">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </
</
```

Comment: Thanks for the basic structure and explanation of what needs to happen.  Am still getting to grips with all this XSLT stuff, but I'm going to go through what you've outlined and also what Mathias has supplied as some code that seems to work fine, and hopefully learn a bit more about this stuff.